# Meaning of 'all yea' in the context

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does this phrase mean? I saw this phrase in the movie *The Post*, 01:44:13. (But i'm not sure if the spelling of the subtitle is correct.) Here is the context.

> All rise.
>
> The Honorable the Chief Justice and the Associate Justices of the
>   Supreme Court of the United States.
>
> **All yea, all yea, all yea.**

Answer (score 1):

The spelling is probably wrong and should be either:

> Oyez, Oyez, Oyez.

or

> Hear ye, hear ye, hear ye.

Both mean approximately the same thing, i.e. "let everyone pay attention to this formal proclamation". 'Oyez' is extremely old language, and very formal, and I would expect to hear it in Britain either in very formal circumstances or hundreds of years ago. I believe it is still used in British courts. But it is possible that the US Supreme Court still uses such language, or did in the seventies when the movie was set.